# Include Path issue running phpunit with phing in a Zend Framework 2 project

Tags: zend-framework2, phpunit, phing

Using Phing I'm trying to run my phpunit tests located in each of my modules. But it's not working. If I call phpunit in each module, the tests run with no problems. But if I call them through a phpunit task in phing, I receive the following error:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase' not found.

Here's a copy of my phpunit task:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="${moduledir}/${modulename}/test/${phpunitbootstrap}" 
         printsummary="true"
         haltonfailure="false" description="test the module" 
         haltonerror="true"
         configuration="${moduledir}/${modulename}/test/phpunit.xml.dist">
    <formatter todir="report" type="xml" outfile="test-report.xml"/>
    <batchtest>
        <fileset dir="${modulename}Test">
            <include name="**/*Test.php"/>
        </fileset>
    </batchtest>
</phpunit>
```

This is called inside a foreach loop to iterate over multiple modules. I'm guessing that either the phpunit task configuration's not setup right, but not sure.

Can anyone help me resolve this?

Comment: Hi, do you found a solution for this problem ? I begin with continuous integration on Jenkins for ZF2 project and i don't know how centralize all of these test in jenkins build report. Thx for your answer !

Comment: @Hooli it looks like they are suggesting Apache Ant instead of Phing.  Look at their template http://jenkins-php.org/

Comment: This may help http://www.zunisoft.com/2008/11/phing-phpunit-and-zend-framework.html

Comment: @Hooli I've not found a solution yet, but am keen to try out the solution from Erik.

Comment: On gituhb i commit a zf2 repo for beginner which include a centralize launch for phpunit, jenkins configuration for CI, doctrine2 and more.... here :https://github.com/jonathangreco/zf2-doctrine-tutorial